# Creating Divided Highway using Nurbs Curves?

Tags: bezier-curves

I am wondering if there is a way for me to create 3D divided highways in Blender using Nurbs curves?

Here is a sample image of a divided highway, as shown in the interchange:

[image]

Comment: Hi, please describe a bit more your project: I guess you are not trying to reproduce exactly such image above... why you need specifically nurbs curves? I think you could have an easier path using just curves (splines), with an extrude amount, eg.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot extrude a complete branch from a vertex mid curve but you can extrude (E-key) a single vertex out (t just hangs loose from the main body of the curve), then extrude it back to the fork location.

[image: curve extrude]

[image: move the vertex back to fork]

Use another curve object that is just a small straight line to bevel the shape of the road.

[image: Bevel shape of road curve]